# How to disable multiple select tag when selecting one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three select tags with values in it. If I select Unlimited in one of the values I want the rest of the two select tags to auto-switch to the same value (Unlimited) and gets disabled.

If I select the option Unlimited from the first select tag the second and thirds value should switch to Unlimited and inputs should get disabled.

If I select the middle option (2nd option) the first select tag and third select tag's value should auto-select to Unlimited and both input fields should get disabled.

Likewise, if I select Unlimited from the last select tag, the first and second should auto-switch to Unlimited and both input fields should get disabled.

Is this possible to do it via pure CSS? If not, how do I achieve it?

```html
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row mb-3">
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per day</label>
  <select id="distancePerDay" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="100">100</option>
   <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
   <option value="200">200</option>
   <option value="250">250</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
   <option value="350">350</option>
   <option value="400">400</option>
   <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per week</label>
  <select id="distancePerWeek" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="700">700</option>
   <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
   <option value="1200">1200</option>
   <option value="1450">1450</option>
   <option value="1700">1700</option>
   <option value="1950">1950</option>
   <option value="2200">2200</option>
   <option value="Unlimited" >Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per month</label>
  <select id="distancePerMonth" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="1500">1500</option>
   <option value="1850">1850</option>
   <option value="2250">2250</option>
   <option value="2600">2600</option>
   <option value="2950">2950</option>
   <option value="3300">3300</option>
   <option value="3650">3650</option>
   <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it is not possible with css

Comment: What is the best possible way to do it via jQuery? Because I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am storing the last known value in a custom attribute `last` in the element before all items were marked Unlimited. When changed to not unlimited it will remember the last known value of each select element and restore it.

If you are looking for a jQuery solution, You add change event listeners to all select elements and if there is any element who has 'Unlimited' as values filter the selects w/o the current element and assign property disabled if 'Unlimited' is selected

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  const isUnlimited = $(this).val() === 'Unlimited';
  $('select')
    .not(this)
    .prop({disabled: isUnlimited})
    .attr('last', function(i,v){ return isUnlimited ? $(this).val() : v; })
    .val(function(i,v){ return isUnlimited ? 'Unlimited' : v === 'Unlimited' ? $(this).attr('last') : v; });
});
```

And using jQuery ensures you write less do more. Snippet attached below.

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  const isUnlimited = $(this).val() === 'Unlimited';
  $('select')
    .not(this)
    .prop({disabled: isUnlimited})
    .attr('last', function(i,v){return isUnlimited ? $(this).val() : v;})
    .val(function(i,v){return isUnlimited ? 'Unlimited' : v === 'Unlimited' ? $(this).attr('last') : v; });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per day</label>
    <select id="distancePerDay" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
      <option value="250">250</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
      <option value="350">350</option>
      <option value="400">400</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per week</label>
    <select id="distancePerWeek" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="700">700</option>
      <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
      <option value="1200">1200</option>
      <option value="1450">1450</option>
      <option value="1700">1700</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="2200">2200</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per month</label>
    <select id="distancePerMonth" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="1500">1500</option>
      <option value="1850">1850</option>
      <option value="2250">2250</option>
      <option value="2600">2600</option>
      <option value="2950">2950</option>
      <option value="3300">3300</option>
      <option value="3650">3650</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo what where? Snippet? see below "show code snippet" click on it

Comment: sorry, but your code didn't respect the OP demand : " the first and second should auto-switch to **Unlimited** "

Comment: @MisterJojo done updated answer. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: well but your code is illogic, when the `Unlimited` value is changed again to a 'normal' value, the 2 other stay on  `Unlimited` , and any change on them set the 2 other to `Unlimited`, so we can't return to 3 'normals' values..!

Comment: yes because the OP didn't mention to go back to original values. Please check the OP

Answer (score 2):

Hi you could do that with `javascript`, I created `validate` function and added `onchange="validate(event)"` in each `select` like so:

```js
const validate = event => {
         
  const dropdowns = ['distancePerDay','distancePerWeek','distancePerMonth'];
  const dropdownsToUpdate = dropdowns.filter(x => x !== event.target.id);
         
  for(let i = 0; i < dropdownsToUpdate.length; i++){    
    const item = document.getElementById(dropdownsToUpdate[i]);
    
    if(event.target.value === 'Unlimited'){
      item.value = 'Unlimited';
      item.setAttribute('disabled', '');     
    }
    else {      
      item.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Distance per day</label>
 <select id="distancePerDay" onchange="validate(event)">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="250">250</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="350">350</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div>
 <label>Distance per week</label>
 <select id="distancePerWeek" onchange="validate(event)">
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
  <option value="1200">1200</option>
  <option value="1450">1450</option>
  <option value="1700">1700</option>
  <option value="1950">1950</option>
  <option value="2200">2200</option>
  <option value="Unlimited" >Unlimited</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div>
 <label>Distance per month</label>
 <select id="distancePerMonth" onchange="validate(event)">
  <option value="1500">1500</option>
  <option value="1850">1850</option>
  <option value="2250">2250</option>
  <option value="2600">2600</option>
  <option value="2950">2950</option>
  <option value="3300">3300</option>
  <option value="3650">3650</option>
  <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS (why jQuery?)

I made a change : if the select with 'Unlimited' is changed again, the 2 other are not disabled any more, and get their ancient value before to be disabled

Second solution, with persistents values in a dataset value:

```
const threeSelects =  document.querySelectorAll('select')
    , C_Unlimited  = 'Unlimited'

threeSelects.forEach(Slc=>{
  Slc.dataset.val = Slc.value
  Slc.onchange=e=>{
    let isDisabled  = (Slc.value===C_Unlimited)
    Slc.dataset.val = Slc.value
    threeSelects.forEach(Sx=>{
      if(Sx!==Slc) Sx.value = (Sx.disabled=isDisabled)? C_Unlimited: Sx.dataset.val
    })
  }
})
```

```js
const threeSelects =  document.querySelectorAll('select')
    , C_Unlimited  = 'Unlimited'

threeSelects.forEach(Slc=>{
  Slc.dataset.val = Slc.value
  Slc.onchange=e=>{
    let isDisabled  = (Slc.value===C_Unlimited)
    Slc.dataset.val = Slc.value
    threeSelects.forEach(Sx=>{
      if(Sx!==Slc) Sx.value = (Sx.disabled=isDisabled)? C_Unlimited: Sx.dataset.val
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.col-12 { display:inline-block; padding:.5em }
label, select { float:left;clear:both }
```

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per day</label>
    <select id="distancePerDay" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
      <option value="250">250</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
      <option value="350">350</option>
      <option value="400">400</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per week</label>
    <select id="distancePerWeek" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="700">700</option>
      <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
      <option value="1200">1200</option>
      <option value="1450">1450</option>
      <option value="1700">1700</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="2200">2200</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per month</label>
    <select id="distancePerMonth" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="1500">1500</option>
      <option value="1850">1850</option>
      <option value="2250">2250</option>
      <option value="2600">2600</option>
      <option value="2950">2950</option>
      <option value="3300">3300</option>
      <option value="3650">3650</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

First solution, with persistents values in a JS table:

```js
const threeSelects = Array
                      .from(document.querySelectorAll('#distancePerDay, #distancePerWeek, #distancePerMonth '))
                      .map(sx => ({ sel: sx, val: sx.value }))
    , C_Unlimited  = 'Unlimited'

threeSelects.forEach(eSchg => { eSchg.sel.onchange = e => {
  eSchg.val = eSchg.sel.value

  threeSelects.forEach(eSx => {
    if (eSx.sel !== eSchg.sel) {
      if (eSchg.sel.value === C_Unlimited) {
        eSx.sel.value = C_Unlimited
        eSx.sel.disabled = true
      }
      else if (eSx.sel.value === C_Unlimited) {
        eSx.sel.value = eSx.val
        eSx.sel.disabled = false
      }
    }
  })
} })
```

```css
.col-12 { display:inline-block; padding:.5em }
label, select { float:left;clear:both }
```

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per day</label>
    <select id="distancePerDay" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
      <option value="250">250</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
      <option value="350">350</option>
      <option value="400">400</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per week</label>
    <select id="distancePerWeek" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="700">700</option>
      <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
      <option value="1200">1200</option>
      <option value="1450">1450</option>
      <option value="1700">1700</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="2200">2200</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <label>Distance per month</label>
    <select id="distancePerMonth" class="form-control custom-select">
      <option value="1500">1500</option>
      <option value="1850">1850</option>
      <option value="2250">2250</option>
      <option value="2600">2600</option>
      <option value="2950">2950</option>
      <option value="3300">3300</option>
      <option value="3650">3650</option>
      <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't enable on a second change to different value

Comment: @charlietfl enable on witch value ? they are on `Unlimited`

Comment: set to unlimited and it works...but then do another change to another value and the others stay disabled

Comment: yes, the two other are on  `Unlimited` value, so the Owner ask a select with`Unlimited` value disable the 2 others, wich mean  `Unlimited` value is exclusive

Comment: Yes....but I doubt they should stay disabled when undone by a different change. I guess it needs clarification from OP. One reason this question should not even be answered. The main one being it is simply a *"give me the codes"* question

Comment: @charlietfl, I change my code, if the 'Unlimited' select is changed again, the other doesn't stay disabled, and return to their value before to be disabled

Comment: Nice that your try with pure js, maybe you can avoid the line `C_Unlimited  = 'Unlimited'` and put the `eSchg.sel.value == 'Unlimited'` result into a var to reduce some lines.

Comment: @the-breaker I can not do this, I have too many years of experience in third-party management (correct sentence)

Answer (score 0):

you can make it easily with jquery, with `not()`.

you can also use `.prop('selectedIndex',0);` to reset your `<select>` when you choose another option to "Unlimited":

```js
$( "select" ).on( "change", function() {
    var sw = $(this).val() == "Unlimited";
    var others = $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', sw);
    sw ? others.val("Unlimited") : others.val()=="Unlimited" ? others.prop('selectedIndex',0) : 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row mb-3">
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per day</label>
  <select id="distancePerDay" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="100">100</option>
   <option value="150" selected="selected">150</option>
   <option value="200">200</option>
   <option value="250">250</option>
   <option value="300">300</option>
   <option value="350">350</option>
   <option value="400">400</option>
   <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per week</label>
  <select id="distancePerWeek" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="700">700</option>
   <option value="950" selected="selected">950</option>
   <option value="1200">1200</option>
   <option value="1450">1450</option>
   <option value="1700">1700</option>
   <option value="1950">1950</option>
   <option value="2200">2200</option>
   <option value="Unlimited" >Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
  <label>Distance per month</label>
  <select id="distancePerMonth" class="form-control custom-select">
   <option value="1500">1500</option>
   <option value="1850">1850</option>
   <option value="2250">2250</option>
   <option value="2600">2600</option>
   <option value="2950">2950</option>
   <option value="3300">3300</option>
   <option value="3650">3650</option>
   <option value="Unlimited">Unlimited</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `others.prop('selectedIndex',0)` is not a good idea, because a change on any select set  the other to the first option